# Set msg.sender in testing

Tags: solidity, contract-design, javascript, testing, truffle-test

I have a Solidity function that manipulates an object. The function only allows this manipulation of the caller msg.sender is owner of that object. Something like this:

```
function Manipulate(uint i)
{
     require(msg.sender == data[i].owner, "Sender is not owner.");
     <manipulate object>;
}
```

In the test that I am writing I am making a test case that checks whether this function behaves as expected. I have 2 user accounts:

```
user1 = accounts[0];
user2 = accounts[1];
```

user2 is owner of the object I want to manipulate. I do the following call in my test:

```
await instance.Manipulate.call(10, {from: user2});
```

Against what I expect, this triggers the Require statetement of my solidity function. So it claims that msg.sender is different from the owner. I modified the string in the Require statement so it also prints msg.sender and the owner of the object I want to manipulate. What I see is that user2 is indeed the owner of the object. However, msg.sender is not user2 but user1. This is weird because I call the Manipulate() function with {from: user2}. So I don't understand why user1 is the msg.sender.

Anyone knows why user1 is the msg.sender and why the {from: user2} statement didn't make user2 the msg.sender ?

Comment: Its your function public or public view ...?

Comment: Just public. It is not a view. Data is being changed, not returned.

Comment: Maybe you are calling from Metamask o Remix with the User1 address. When a "public" function change a value need to be signed. Then you need your privatekey instead a single public address as User2.

Comment: I am not using metamask or Remix. I am connected to Ganache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "=" with "==" in require statement : `require(msg.sender == data[i].owner, "Sender is not owner.");`

Comment: Yes, that was an error I made in this post. But in my code I do have "==" so that's not the problem. I corrected it in my original post.

Comment: try this await instance.methods.Manipulate(10).call({from:user2});
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an error: instance.methods.Manipulate is not a function.

Comment: try it without method (i.e )await instance.Manipulate(10).call({from:user2});

Comment: I tried what you said. I also was unable to call it this way, I think because the function is not a view function but it manipulates data. However, I solved the problem. My function Manpulate() has 3 parameters. But when I called it, I was only passing 2 parameters. So because {from: user2} was at the third position, the code wrongly took this as the third parameter of the function. I know, stupid mistake of me :-). Thanks for the help !!!